# How can I backup target files with xcopy?

Tags: batch-file, backup, xcopy

I change my project files on live by copying only the changed files with one xcopy command. Is it possible to back-up the target files (only the changing ones) into another location with xcopy? Or with a batch script?

Sorry, my question is not clear enough, here are some further explanation:

I have files in folder A that I xcopy to folder B. But I need to backup the files in folder B that are overwritten. How can I do this the easiest way?

Thanks.

Comment: `Robocopy` only copies changed files and has a `/mir` mirror backup switch, if you want a mirror backup.

Answer (score 0):

```
xcopy /d
```

from the xcopy help

```
/D:mm-dd-yyyy
                Copy files changed on or after the specified date.
                If no date is given, copy only files whose
                source date/time is newer than the destination time.
```